# converting from dataset to macro variables

Tags: sas

I have the below dataset called myDS with only 1 row, the number of columns can be variable

Below I have showed 4 columns but I can have less or more than 4

```
   A        B        C        D

   3        4        "hello"        "apple"
```

I would like to create a macro that takes the input as the dataset DS 
and outputs macro variables named after the column

so for example

&A should be 3 
and &B should be 4 
&C should be "hello"

is this doable? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Chris J's suggestion;

```
%macro to_vars(ds);
data _null_;
set &ds;
array nums[*] _numeric_;
array chars[*] _character_;

do i=1 to dim(nums);
   call symputx(vname(nums[i]),nums[i],'G');
end;
do i=1 to dim(chars);
   call symputx(vname(chars[i]),chars[i],'G');
end;
run;
%mend;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SAS 9.2 then the following will work. [adapted from [SAS documentation]](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000127856.htm)

**update:** Works just fine in SAS 9.1 too.

[note: the character variables do not have a quote around them in the macros created. But, if your dataset comes with character variables with embeded double/single quotes then the macro variables will also have them]

```
%let dsid=%sysfunc(open(myDS,i));/*open the dataset which has macro vars to read in cols*/
%syscall set(dsid); /*no leading ampersand with %SYSCALL */
%let rc=%sysfunc(fetchobs(&dsid,1));/*just reading 1 obs*/
%let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid));/*close dataset after reading*/
%put _user_;
```

`%Put _user_` writes the following to the log:

```
GLOBAL A 3
GLOBAL B 4
GLOBAL C hello
GLOBAL D apple
```

[above output is exactly the same as what @DomPazz macro solution provides using the following dataset]

```
data myDS;
A=3;
B=4;
C="hello";
D="apple";
run;
```

So, as you can see all the variables in your myDS dataset are mapped to respective macro variables.
You could refer to [Functions and CALL Routines by Category](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245860.htm) to understand the various SAS functions used in the above code.

Comment: Wow, interesting solution.  I had no idea it could be done this way.  It would be nice if you converted into a macro and added error checking etc...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's doable. You could transpose the data into two columns, or use two arrays - one for the numeric columns, another for the character columns,  iterating over each, using the vname() function to get the column name.

Comment: Please can you give me a simple example using my dummy dataset. I am a bit stuck